# Setblock command block with command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am confused about why this doesn't work.
Pls help me. MC 1.12.2

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block 11 replace {Command:"/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"iron_ingot",Count:1,tag:{}}}"}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you explain what you want to have happen in the game with the command you want to write?

Comment: I want someone to be able to 'upgrade' their generator by activating the command block and placing another one it its given area that will link with the redstone clock I have working with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape special characters when inside quotation marks.

In this case `Command` is a string so it's data is inside quotation marks.  Inside that string is `id` which is another string.  In your case you have that within quotation marks.  The inner quotation marks have to be escaped.

Here is the command with escaped quotation marks:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block 11 replace {Command:"/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:\"iron_ingot\",Count:1,tag:{}}}"}
```

While I don't recommend it, you can also omit the quotations around the id data and it functions properly in 1.12.2:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block 11 replace {Command:"/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:iron_ingot,Count:1,tag:{}}}"}
```

You can also specify the data type for count section, omit tag in the summon command, and omit the slash in the summon command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block 11 replace {Command:"summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:\"minecraft:iron_ingot\",Count:1b}}"}
```

Note:  This will produce a conditional impulse block facing South.

Comment: How to do I make it so that it doesn't have to be conditional without changing it or make it so that it will summon the object without me  adding stuff

Comment: After reading your comments, it sounds like you just want a command block that is triggered by redstone.  You specified a data value of 11.  (`... minecraft:command_block 11 replace ...`)  Use 0 instead.  (`... minecraft:command_block 0 replace ...`)  Unless you need it to face South, then use 3.